# Java running exe file from package

Tags: java, eclipse

i tried to run an exe file from the same package the program is in using

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("prog.exe");
```

and

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("prog.exe"));
```

but they both give me errors. I made sure there was no spelling error in the name and it still gave me an error. is there another way to do this without having to use the entire directory?

Comment: Please provide the stack trace of the first approach. You second approach is not really about running an executable but about opening a file using the configured default application.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean

Comment: "same package"? What does that even mean. An `.exe` file is unrelated to the Java class package directory structure, or are you saying that you placed an `.exe` file next to the `.class` file?.

Comment: @Gray Post the error messages that you get.

Comment: yeah, in eclipse you can drag files into a package with classes and other stuff, so i dragged in the prog.exe file and tried to open it within the package using a class

Comment: @NikG the error message is too long for me to post

Comment: @Gray Don't place the .exe within the `src` directory of your package, instead, place in the directort above the `src` directory

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy it from the resource which might be in a jar to an absolute path. Also make sure to get the path correct. If prog.exe is in the same directory a class in package pkg, then you need to add `pkg/` to the resource name.

```
File tmpCopy = File.createTempFile("prog", ".exe");
Files.copy(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("pkg/prog.exe"), tmpCopy.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
// Needed on Linux/Mac only ---Files.setPosixFilePermissions(tmpCopy.toPath(), PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rwxrwxrwx"));
Process p = new ProcessBuilder(tmpCopy.getAbsolutePath()).inheritIO().start();
p.waitFor();
```

Comment: that gives me an error with:     

     Files.copy(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("brickbreaker.exe"), tmpCopy.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

Comment: I edited the answer to handle one possibility but it would be better to know the complete error.